# Sort by most recent but keep together by another ID column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I am trying to get some sorting and keep together (not really grouping) working.
In my sample data I would like to keep the DealerIDs together, sorted by IsPrimaryDealer DESC, but show the group (ok maybe it is grouping) of dealers by the ones with the most recent entry.

Result set 2 is the closest, but Grant and his brother should be displayed as the first two rows, in that order. (Grant should be row 1, Grants Brother row 2 because Grants Brother was the most recently added)

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (
    DealerPK int not null IDENTITY(1,1), DealerID int, 
    IsPrimaryDealer bit, DealerName varchar(50), DateAdded datetime
)

INSERT INTO @temp VALUES
(1, 1, 'Bob', GETDATE() - 7),
(2, 1, 'Robert', GETDATE() - 7),
(3, 1, 'Grant', GETDATE() - 7),
(3, 0, 'Grants Brother', GETDATE() - 1),
(2, 0, 'Roberts Nephew', GETDATE() - 2),
(1, 0, 'Bobs Cousin', GETDATE() - 3)

-- Data As Entered
SELECT * FROM @temp
-- Data Attempt at Row Numbering
SELECT *, intPosition = 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IsPrimaryDealer ORDER BY DealerID, IsPrimaryDealer DESC)
FROM @temp
ORDER BY DateAdded DESC
-- Data Attempt By DateAdded
SELECT *, intPosition = 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DealerID ORDER BY DateAdded DESC)
FROM @temp
ORDER BY intPosition, DateAdded
```

Expected Result

```
PK  DID IsPr    Name            DateAdded
3    3  1       Grant           2015-10-08 17:14:26.497
4    3  0       Grants Brother  2015-10-14 17:14:26.497
2    2  1       Robert          2015-10-08 17:14:26.497
5    2  0       Roberts Nephew  2015-10-13 17:14:26.497
1    1  1       Bob             2015-10-08 17:14:26.497
6    1  0       Bobs Cousin     2015-10-12 17:14:26.497
```

Comment: Can you post your expected result?

Comment: hmmm, hard to do that (disregard PK in above comment). If you can run the temp above in OP, should be Grant, his brother, Robert, his Nephew, and then Bob and his Cousin

Comment: Kindly edit your question, and post the expected result.

Comment: just realized I could do that, and did

Comment: `;WITH Cte AS(
 SELECT *,
  mx = MAX(DateAdded) OVER(PARTITION BY DealerID)
 FROM @temp
)
SELECT * FROM Cte
ORDER BY mx DESC, DealerID, IsPrimaryDealer DESC`

Comment: Thanks @FelixPamittan it works a treat! And I added a new record, Roberts Sister, todays date, and then his group moved to first position showing Robert First, Roberts Cousin, and then Roberts Sister grouped together in order nicely! Can you post your comment as answer so I can accept? Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested by OP:

```
;WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *, 
        mx = MAX(DateAdded) OVER(PARTITION BY DealerID) FROM @temp
) 
SELECT * 
FROM Cte 
ORDER BY mx DESC, DealerID, IsPrimaryDealer DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Hope i understood your question,
This query results expected output : 

SELECT Row_number()
                OVER (
                  PARTITION BY DealerID
                  ORDER BY DealerPK)RN,
              DealerPK,
              DealerID,
              IsPrimaryDealer,
              DealerName,
              DateAdded
       FROM   #temp
       ORDER  BY DealerID DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt and I see what you are heading for but it doesn't work because if I add a new record, say Roberts Sister, DealerID 2, IsPrimaryDealer 0, then Roberts group of records do not move up to the first position. Felix Pamittans comment above under the original post works.