# mongoDB sort on two fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongodb document something like below :

```
 {

        "match_key" : 44801,
        "total_points" : 10.00,


    },
    {
        "match_key" : 44901,
        "total_points" : 8.00,
    },
   {
        "match_key" : 44901,
        "total_points" : 7.00,
    },

   {
        "match_key" : 44901,
        "total_points" : 11.00,
    },
    {

    "match_key" : 44801,
    "total_points" : 7.00,


}
```

I want to sort the above docs ,but want to keep the documents with same match_key together.

**Actual result :**

```
 {
        "match_key" : 44901,
        "total_points" : 11.00,
    }
,
 {

        "match_key" : 44801,
        "total_points" : 10.00,


    },
{
        "match_key" : 44901,
        "total_points" : 8.00,
    },

{

    "match_key" : 44801,
    "total_points" : 7.00,


}

 {
        "match_key" : 44901,
        "total_points" : 6.00,
    },
```

But you see that same match keys are not together.

**Expected result :**

```
{
        "match_key" : 44901,
        "total_points" : 11.00,
    },
{
        "match_key" : 44901,
        "total_points" : 8.00,
    },
{
        "match_key" : 44901,
        "total_points" : 7.00,
    },
{

        "match_key" : 44801,
        "total_points" : 10.00,


    },
{

        "match_key" : 44801,
        "total_points" : 6.00,


    },
```

Such that docs with same_match key are in descending  order.

This is what I tried doing :

```
 db.collection.aggregate(
    [
      { $match: { match_key:{$in:[44801,45910]}}},
      { $sort: {total_points:1,match_key:1} }
    ]
 )
```

This is some sql equivalent of the question ,I am trying to ask -[Sort by most recent but keep together by another ID column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33160399/sort-by-most-recent-but-keep-together-by-another-id-column)

My main motive here is to  sort the docs and keep the docs with same match_key together but in order
/**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split this `$sort` into two stages like below :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      match_key: {
        $in: [
          44801,
          45910
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      total_points: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      match_key: -1
    }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sJz_rw6rji3)

**Note :** As we've `$match` as first stage, we should be good to do sorting, but even though as we need to do sort twice, try to keep your dataset as low as possible, You need to have two [Single-field-index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-single/index.html) on two of your fields `total_points` & `match_key`.

**Issue :**
 So when you do this : `{ $sort: {total_points:-1,match_key:1} }` your query is sorting on `total_points :1` field first & if it finds two docs with same `total_points` value then it would go to `match_key:1` will sort those two docs to keep them in order.

**Example of issue :** Using compound sorting like above you would get below result

```
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    "match_key": 44801,
    "total_points": 10
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003"),
    "match_key": 45910,
    "total_points": 10
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000005"),
    "match_key": 44801,
    "total_points": 7
  }
```

If you see `total_points` are sorted in order, with first priority is on `total_points` & since there are two docs with `"total_points": 10` it kicks in second priority of `match_key`. Anyway if you want to sort like `11->10->7` you need to use descending mechanism with `-1` but not `1` (which is ascending).

Comment: Whoa ,that worked :) .Thanks for the explaination :)